# org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I'm trying to connect to HiveServer2 and run queries from my java application. When I run on my localserver(Hive version: `2.1.1`). It works perfectly with the following dependencies:

```
compile('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1')

compile ('org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:2.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate', module: '*'
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"    }

compile ('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.0.0'){
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
}
```

But when I run on a remote server(Hive version: `0.13.1-SNAPSHOT`). It throws the below mentioned error. I got to know that, the issue is with hive-jdbc, hadoop-core and hadoop-common versions. Can anyone let me know which versions of those dependencies I need to be using for Hive `0.13.1-SNAPSHOT`

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few trail and errors I fixed the version issue. The issue is hive-jdbc:2.1.0 is not backward compatible with Hive 0.13.1-SNAPSHOT, we need to use hive-jdbc:0.13.1 to make it work. Below code works with no doubt.

```
compile('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1')

compile ('org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:0.13.1'){
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate', module: '*'
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"    }

compile ('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.0.0'){
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
}
```